# Odd text framing in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ide

[image: Simple windows app]

I don't understand why suddenly this program has incorrect framing around blocks of code.  It appears to also be linked to hovering over a variable or type and having it report erroneous information.  The little '-' icon isn't in the right place either for collapsing an entire function or block.  Instead it shows up in the middle of functions.

Problem exists on WIN-10 laptop (HP ZBook with Rad Studio 10.3 or 10.4)

I have tried deleting the identcache, dproj.local and res files with no change.

Is there not some way to tell whatever does this to 'rework' it's image so it comes out correct?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the code editor. The code shown is fine. Have you tried upgrading to the latest Rad Studio 11 and see if the problem continues?

Comment: It happened to me too, I remedied it by scrolling with the mouse wheel

Comment: Sometimes this happens when the file contains mixed line endings: LF only and CR+LF. But don't think that's the case here.

Comment: This happens to me too regularly. Sometimes it can be resolved by making changes to the code, forcing the IDE to reparse it. (For instance, type a character somewhere at the top of the problematic region and then remove it.) A bit more aggressive: Closing and then reopening the project may fix it. Even more aggressive: Restart RAD Studio. If nothing works and you can consistently reproduce the issue in some particular source code file, then attach it in a bug report to Embarcadero.

Comment: Most aggressive: Deactivate that block highlighting feature in the options and use the CnPack plugin instead.

Comment: It's possible that this code might have some errant CR or LF characters.  It's a program that parses OS9-68K floppy disk images to resize and be able to write to a different format disk.  So there might be remnants of OS9 formatting.  I'll check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears to be solved.  I used my antique Codewright Editor to fix the line endings.  Now with all endings as \r\n rather than some imported blocks of code with single \r (OS9 format) the text no longer has the strange squigly's and odd grouping.  I'm going to suggest this is one huge major bug in the Delphi IDE.  If the editor sees embedded CR without the trailing LF in some places and not in others it should pop up with a warning and even an option to 'fix' the file.  Although the editor has the look of Codewright with search for regular expressions it was the hex beside ascii that verified I had single $0D characters between lines and not $0D$0A.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others this most likely comes from strange characters in your code. Easiest "on board" way to clean code from unwanted invisible characters is to us the format command. So any time I encounter weird behavior in code, I just do a quick format.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using cnpack. It has many improvements to IDE and it is open source. And also is always updated for new Delphi releases.

Comment: This should be comment because it doesn't answer op's question